# Varnish + Mod_pagespeed + Tomcat for a Spring MVC webapp

Tags: tomcat, optimization, nginx, varnish, mod-pagespeed

I all,

I am building a new Spring MVC web app that runs on Tomcat. To make the site as fast as possible, I've decided to use Varnish in front of it, but I'm also considering using mod_pagespeed (bundled in a basic Apache or Nginx) to do some automatic optimization - what mod_pagespeed is good for.

The result would be this:

Pound (for HTTPS) -> Varnish -> Mod_pagespeed (in apache or nginx) -> Tomcat

Does this sound like a good architecture to get the fastest speed possible? Or, is this making things too complex for marginal improvement?

If mod_pagespeed is a good stategy, would you use Apache or Nginx as a proxy? Please consider that the actual webserver is Tomcat and these extra layers are only for optimization and not proxying...

PS: I have looked at WRO4J, but this doesn't look like a replacement for mod_pagespeed (at first sight).

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would change mod_pagespeed to be before varnish, so varnish can cache the actual modified (minified, resized, etc.) assets coming from mod_pagespeed.

Comment: Erm, this is wrong. Varnish is in front, so it can cache the output generated by mod_pagespeed. Otherwise mod_pagespeed will need to process each and every request.

Comment: That's what I meant exactly with my comment. Sorry if I wasn't clear. Your order seemed confusing at first.